# How to rotate the screen when I play a video?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, rotation, ios8

The code I was using to rotate the screen when playing a video from webview is not longer working in iOS 8, is there another way to do that in iOS 8 ?

UPDATE

**I am using this code now**

```
#define IS_OS_6_OR_LATER    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 6.0)
#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)

if(IS_OS_6_OR_LATER){

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeStarted:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeFinished:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerWillExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];

}

if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeStarted:) name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification object:self.view.window];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeFinished:) name:UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification object:self.view.window];

}
```

**in ios 7 I used this one**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeStarted:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeFinished:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerWillExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];

-(void)youTubeStarted{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying = YES;
}

-(void)youTubeFinished{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying = NO;
}
```

But none of them is working

Comment: What code were you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];    
NSString *reqSysVer8 = @"8.0";
if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer8 options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
    //iOS8.0 or greater (bounds ARE orientation dependant)
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {
        NSLog(@"Launch orientation >iOS8 portrait - INVERSING");
        //portrait, inverse dimensions
        _screenFrame.size.width = bounds.size.height;
        _screenFrame.size.height = bounds.size.width;
    }
    else {
        _screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    }
```